# Code to hide price display suffix stopped working - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

Using "[Removing price suffix based on user role](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60528989/11987538)" to hide the price suffix from all user roles except a Trade user and Admin. It seems to have stopped working.  Not sure what has changed, can anyone see anything wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked by inspecting the price element if anything is printed?

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply.  The  price suffix is in my Woo settings and with this snippet active it is hiding it.  When I inspect the price element the suffix isnt there at all.  If I turn off this snippet the suffix is there, and is there for all user roles. This snippet used to perfectly hide the snippet only for the user roles requested.  Not sure what has affected it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check another plugin has add_filter for woocommerce_get_price_suffix or not.
You can check it by changing the priority for your hook.

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'custom_woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 99, 4 );

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I tried changing the last line of code but it hasn't fixed it. When it comes to troubleshooting for hooks I am a novice. I cant think of any plugin I have installed recently that would affect it.

Comment: What is the product type for this hook?

Comment: Hi there, they are all simple products. They are in a Wholesale category, and are only visible (as is the Page they're on) to the default_wholesaler user role. The price suffix is in the main Woo setting and this code should hide the suffix from everyone except that wholesaler role and Admin. However the exceptions or those user types seem to have stopped working.

Comment: Weirdly it seems to have just fixed itself. I use a code snippets plugin and I noticed you can change the priority there too, so I set it to 99 same as your code. That didnt work. Then I set them both back to 10 but removed the admin user. Seems to work again, except Admin no longer sees it the same way, which I can live with. Thanks for your help!